# Most Efficient way to enumerate all registry keys

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I am using following function to enumerate all registry keys for a particular key and subkey in a vector and return it.

But this code seems to run very slow for large Key Values, like for above 200000+ keys, it takes more than 5 minutes to complete.
Just want to know how can I make it more efficient.

```
vector<string> CRegistryAPI::EnumKeys(HKEY RootKey, string SubKey)
{
    DWORD keyLen = 255;
    int index = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    PFILETIME lastWrite = 0;
    HKEY hKey = 0;
    char keyName[255];
    vector<string> keyList;

    if (RegOpenKeyExA(RootKey, SubKey.c_str(), 0, KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS,&hKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return keyList;
    do
    {
        ret = RegEnumKeyExA(hKey, index, keyName, &keyLen, 0, 0, 0, lastWrite);
        if (ret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            keyList.push_back(keyName);
        }
        index ++;
        keyLen = 255; 
    }
    while (ret == ERROR_SUCCESS);

    if (hKey != NULL)
        RegCloseKey(hKey);

    return keyList;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It takes a long time to enumerate that many keys

Comment: Why do you want to enumerate all keys?

Comment: writing a registry cleaner tool. I have an equivalent C# function thats taking half its time, which is strange.

Comment: `#define UNICODE` before include `<windows.h>`. replace `string` with `wstring`. remove the `A` suffixes in the function names. not just more efficient but also more **correct**. and readable. while we're talking, *why* did you choose to add complexity and inefficiency? for that matter, what's the point of the `C` prefix for the class name? is this all just blindly copying Microsoft conventions from 1995? if so, then good advice: just don't do that. less work, better result.

Answer (score 1):

One optimization you can do is use [`RegQueryInfoKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724902.aspx) to query information about a given key before then enumerating its contents. For instance, you can preallocate your vector's capacity so it does not have to be reallocated multiple times during the enumeration:

```
RegQueryInfoKey(hKey, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &dwNumValues, 0, 0, 0, 0);
keyList.reserve(keyList.size()+dwNumValues);
```

Also, your enumeration is not ensuring your buffer is null-terminated when pushing it into the vector. Even if it were, your way of pushing currently requires `std::string` to calculate the buffer length each time. You should instead use the buffer length that is returned to you:

```
keyList.push_back(string(keyName, keyLen));
```